# Move position of jQueryUI autocomplete

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

How do I move the position of the jQueryUI autocomplete display list down a bit?

I can select it by using `var ul=$("#field").autocomplete().autocomplete('widget');`.

Using `offset()` on `ul`, however, doesn't work as `ul` is positioned when the widget is opened.

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/tu0usot8/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "position option" field like in the following snippet where I moved 100 right the autocomplete.

```
var ul=$("#field").autocomplete({
    source: countries_starting_with_A,
    minLength: 1,
    position: { my : "left top+20", at: "left bottom" },
    select: function(event, ui) {
............................................
```

For details you may see [position](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/)

```js
$(function () {
  var countries_starting_with_A = [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "value": "Afghanistan",
      "label": "Afghanistan"
    },
    {
      "id": "17",
      "value": "Albania",
      "label": "Albania"
    },
    {
      "id": "18",
      "value": "Algeria",
      "label": "Algeria"
    },
    {
      "id": "20",
      "value": "American Samoa",
      "label": "American Samoa"
    },
    {
      "id": "22",
      "value": "Andorra",
      "label": "Andorra"
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "value": "Angola",
      "label": "Angola"
    },
    {
      "id": "11",
      "value": "Anguilla",
      "label": "Anguilla"
    },
    {
      "id": "23",
      "value": "Antarctica",
      "label": "Antarctica"
    },
    {
      "id": "24",
      "value": "Antigua and Barbuda",
      "label": "Antigua and Barbuda"
    },
    {
      "id": "25",
      "value": "Argentina",
      "label": "Argentina"
    },
    {
      "id": "26",
      "value": "Armenia",
      "label": "Armenia"
    },
    {
      "id": "27",
      "value": "Aruba",
      "label": "Aruba"
    },
    {
      "id": "28",
      "value": "Australia",
      "label": "Australia"
    },
    {
      "id": "29",
      "value": "Austria",
      "label": "Austria"
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "value": "Azerbaijan",
      "label": "Azerbaijan"
    }
  ];

  var ul=$("#field").autocomplete({
    source: countries_starting_with_A,
    minLength: 1,
    position: { my : "left top+20", at: "left bottom" },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      // feed hidden id field
      $("#field_id").val(ui.item.id);
      // update number of returned rows
      $('#results_count').html('');
    },
    open: function(event, ui) {
      // update number of returned rows
      var len = $('.ui-autocomplete > li').length;
      $('#results_count').html('(#' + len + ')');
    },
    close: function(event, ui) {
      // update number of returned rows
      $('#results_count').html('');
    },
    // mustMatch implementation
    change: function (event, ui) {
      if (ui.item === null) {
        $(this).val('');
        $('#field_id').val('');
      }
    }
  }).autocomplete('widget');
  console.log(ul)

  // mustMatch (no value) implementation
  $("#field").focusout(function() {
    if ($("#field").val() === '') {
      $('#field_id').val('');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<label for="field_id">ID</label>
<input id="field_id" type="text" style="width: 40px;">
<label for="field">Countries (starting with A)</label>
<input id="field" type="text" style="width: 200px;">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span id="results_count"></span>
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="OK">
```

Comment: These seems to be the more "correct" solution, however, implementation currently shows it moving to the right instead of down.  Are we able to do relative movements?

Comment: I updated the snippet, now as you do with offset I repeated with position.

Comment: Ah, there you got it!  Mind explaining why `{ my : "left top+20", at: "left bottom" }` does what it does?

Comment: yep, it does what you tried to do with offset because the position of the element now is top+20 against the "at" your input where it must be at left and bottom position.

Comment: My offset solution worked as well.  I just feel  your solution is the more official way to do it.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is the best, but one option is:

```
open: function(event, ui) {
      var ul = $(this).autocomplete('widget'),offset=ul.offset();
      ul.offset({top:offset.top+20}) //Move 20px down
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

The jQueryUI plugin changes the autocomplete element style so it will be positioned next to the text field.
Because the style attribute can be overriden only using the `!important` keyword, and it is not recommended to change the code of the plugin to bypass that, you can use the following CSS:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
  top: 100px !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi Eburge,  Do you know if the position of the autocomplete list is always the same regardless of theme, etc?